# Advanced Filter - Variable not defined

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an advanced filter in vba and paste the unique content to a new sheet. I however receive an error stating "variable not defined" - Please note, I am a complete beginner for VBA

I am trying to copy values from a sheet and paste it to a new one. There are however duplicates and I have tried the advanced filter method in vba. The copy of the data should only apply if 1 or 2 of a certain select column is blank.

```
Sub copyuniqval()

    shBudget.Range("A2:c1048576").ClearContents
    Dim lngLastRow As Long: lngLastRow = shProject.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    If shProject.Range("K1048576").End(xlUp).Row = "" And shProject.Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Row = "" Then
        MsgBox "Do Nothing"
    Else
        shProject.Range("A5:A" & lngLastRow).AdvancedFilter_
        Action = xlFilterCopy_
        CopyToRange = shBudget.Range("A2")
        Unique = True
End Sub
```

It should look at column K and L, if it is blank, msgBox with "Do Nothing". If it is not blank, then copy the values in column A, and paste them in a new sheet. And paste only the unique values.
However, with my code above, I get a `compile error: Variable not defined`

Comment: You are missing an `End If` - and you need a line continuation character and commas between the parameters of the `Range.AutoFilter` portion.

Comment: Also - a `.Row`, which represents the row number, will never `= ""`. So `shProject.Range("K1048576").End(xlUp).Row = "" And shProject.Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Row = ""` will always be `False`. I'm assuming you don't want the instances of `.Row`.

Comment: At BigBen, Correct. I don't want a False. Would you suggest any other code that would help for this?

Comment: Remove both instances of `.Row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named arguments need a colon before the = sign (as well as commas between, and line continuation characters for all relevant lines):

```
shProject.Range("A5:A" & lngLastRow).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=shBudget.Range("A2"), _
        Unique:=True
```

Comment: Thank you BigBen, Rory. Your suggestion fixed the bugs and it is working well now.